# Why is 'stod' still not declared in this scope even after C++11 is enabled and I have included string?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having an error while trying to convert a string vector to a double vector. The error keeps saying:

```
error: 'stod' was not declared in this scope
```

Even though I enabled C++11 for my compiler and I used `#include <string>` I also used `using namespace std;` And it still didn't work.

The code is is down below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using stod;
transform(userNums.begin(), userNums.end(), back_inserter(convUserNums), [](const string & astr){ return stod( astr) ; } ) ;
```

Comment: This isn't anywhere near enough of your code to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

[`stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is defined in the `namespace std`. You should call it like `std::stod`.

Or put `using namespace std;` above.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include the necessary header and [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) directive.

```
#include <string>

using std::stod;

int main( const int, const char** )
{
    stod( "3.4" );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please find the std::stod documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). Note that this function will [throw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) both [std::invalid_argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) and [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exceptions. A [try-catch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) block is highly recommended.

The example was built with `g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++11` under `gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)`.

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis after `main`.

Comment: This didn't work either. :/ Is it possible that me using codeblocks 16.01 has something to do with this?

Comment: How are you compiling the code?  What are the flags you supply to the compiler?

Comment: I am using the [-std=c++11] flag, and I am compiling it with a GNU GCC Compiler. Sorry i'm a bit new-ish to C++.

Comment: Which terminal would you find this in? My build terminal is completely different.